# Equivalent of __declspec( naked ) in gcc/g++

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

What is the equivalent of `__declspec( naked )` in **gcc/g++**? `__declspec( naked )` is actually used to declare a function without any epilogue and prologue.

Comment: http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=15

Comment: @SigTerm I was about to post that link, it's a neat hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no such equivalent with a recent GCC under Linux. The compiler emit prologues and epilogues when appropriate, and you should leave that decision to it. It may be quite good at making prologues or epilogues quite small, or even sometimes non-existent.

You could code your function in assembly. Or you can put asm statements inside your function.

And you did not tell why you want to do that. What is your goal, and why precisely are you asking?

Comment: You are wrong, I myself once used such a thing, but can't remember now.

Comment: You did it with GCC? The page referenced by SigTerm is in accordance with what I said: if you want no prologue or epilogue with GCC and Linux (on x86 or AMD64 target machines), use asm.

Comment: Well, actually there is, but only for some (embedded) architectures, as you imply yourself in a comment.

Comment: It is important to be able to do naked functions in the case of embedded systems, since the stack lies in RAM and avoiding it is useful to keep code execution in ROM (as long as the RAM was not initialized for an example).

Comment: This answer is wrong, as snogglethorpe says in the other answer, the naked attribute gets rid of all prologue and epilogue, but depending on the architecture it will still do a linked branch without putting the old contents of the link register on the stack. For example, GCC as of writing will do a bl and then you must do a bx lr in your naked function to return back.

Answer (score 14):

On some architectures, gcc supports an attribute called "naked"; the most recent [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) I have give this list of architectures: ARM, AVR, MCORE, RX and SPU.

*If* you are using one of those architectures (gcc will give you a warning if you try to use it and it isn't supported), the attribute can be used like this:

```
__attribute__ ((naked)) int fun ()
{
}
```

[There's been a bit of discussion recently on the gcc developer list about adding the "naked" attribute as a more general feature, and trying to support it on more architectures, but obviously that doesn't help you :).]

Comment: GCC8 supports this for x86.  https://godbolt.org/z/cPrxan5Tv.  Earlier GCC doesn't.