# Trying to compile a module on linux with gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, compilation

Here a error i getting when compile:

b-spec/BS_Linux_Dynamic.cpp:57:11: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
make[1]: *** [Release/b-spec/BS_Linux_Dynamic.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mm/Плот/metamod-1.19/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2

here is source:
http://pastebin.com/rhpPrmHv

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
__declspec(naked) void CheckProtocol_AsmHelper_LDyn() {
```

This doesn't compile because `__declspec(naked)` is a Microsoft extension that is not supported by `gcc`.

See [Equivalent of __declspec( naked ) in gcc/g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937536/equivalent-of-declspec-naked-in-gcc-g)

Comment: Ok when i change "_declspec(naked)" to "__attribute__(naked)" i get this http://pastebin.com/JsDLRnEB

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `asm()` instead of `__asm{}`? Since the linux kernel does it this way as well, why don't you. Also, why are you using c++ to write a kernel module?

Oh! And use `__attribute__((naked))`.

EDIT:

You need to end each call to `asm()` with a semicolon. Also, `asm()` takes a string as an argument, so you need to quote-wrap your assembly code. You also need to use `\n` and `\t` to indicate tabs and newlines in those strings.

Comment: Ok, here the error log - http://pastebin.com/tEQcQypn
here the edit - http://pastebin.com/g9s4JRee